# How to change the order of teams in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I created few teams but I do not like the order which they show up

[image]

Is there a way to, for example, have "Gitlab" show before "Personal Boards"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there's no native functionality to reorder teams. That would be nice.

But there's a somewhat crude workaround. You can use Unicode [emoji characters](https://emojipedia.org/) as the prefix of a team name and that'll put your team in different positions on your boards page.

[image: Example on the Web]

**Caveats**

1. You'll notice the positions are different on the web vs. mobile. On the web my emoji prefixed team names show up on the top. On mobile, those teams show at the bottom.
2. Team names in drop down lists are ordered alphabetically, and are *not* keyboard friendly. You can't type the first character to jump to it.

[image: Team names in web drop down]